# Problems with Excel formulas

Tags: excel

I'm trying to sum the values of the "Costo" column if the "A" column and "X" column has 1 (by the same way if the column "A" has 2 or 3 and the "X" column has 1).

```
X   Costo   A   R   Obj1    Obj2    Obj3    Obj4    Obj5    Obj6    Obj7    Obj8    Obj9

0   9265    2   2   20500   18490   40245   16790   39460   14960   22145   52750   60065
1   6505    3   1   30025   20170   57470   22830   61055   45760   44405   53165   60455
0   8750    2   2   12550   28845   40250   26460   10025   18125   57925   49420   9775
0   7910    1   1   25735   13060   59740   23325   53780   19160   52555   68720   11285
1   5710    2   1   19125   26630   56860   27930   74975   32550   39820   56835   67820
0   5335    1   2   35685   8145    30635   28530   4185    46775   63620   12155   58820
1   5185    1   2   42430   34345   52665   33105   28940   26405   28120   66590   51595
0   7060    2   2   13640   32910   42820   16665   61115   48125   66510   12785   57745
0   6455    1   1   36865   35120   31375   13190   62120   32010   38515   20845   25935
0   6560    1   2   25395   10675   15155   16900   53535   31510   30110   68735   63165
0   8500    1   2   42775   29740   28170   34890   48830   45105   73020   14765   14500
1   5180    3   1   45975   6410    49535   13540   50200   49500   59665   10150   32720
0   8820    3   2   23145   39485   45590   15290   55855   35725   42115   43465   56280
```

(the table is an extract of my data)

In Excel I put this formula for solve my problem:

```
=SUMA(B1:B487(SI(Y(A1:A487=1,C1:C487=1),"","")))
```

But I got the value of `#¡REF!`

I tried with `SUMAR.SI` function:

```
=SUMAR.SI(B1:B487,Y(A1:A487=1,C1:C487=1))
```

But the result is `0`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use a `SUMIFS` (SUMAR.SIS?) instead of `SUMIF` and have a separate condition for each column.

Comment: Try `=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(B1:B487, A1:A487, 1, C1:C487, 1)`. More information at [función SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO](https://support.office.com/es-es/Article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

Copying a Comment from @Jeeped which seemed acceptable to OP, for the sake of an answer:

```
=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(B1:B487, A1:A487, 1, C1:C487, 1)
```

> More information at función SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO.